# Clustering on 97 features of categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, categorical-data, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to apply unsupervised learning on a data with 97 features and around 6500 rows/samples. All features have discrete data (mostly from 1-10) with some being binary (0/1). What are some of the best clustering algorithms to apply on this data. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say which clustering algo will perform best on your given dataset. You just have to try several methodologies and inspect the final results that you get. Here are several clustering algos that you can try.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20Algorithms%20Compared.ipynb

Here is a small sample.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df_cars = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
df_cars.head()

from numpy import unique
from numpy import where
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot

# define dataset
X = df_cars[['mpg','hp']]


# define the model
model = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
# fit the model
model.fit(X)

# assign a cluster to each example
yhat = model.predict(X)

X['kmeans']=yhat

pyplot.scatter(X['mpg'], X['hp'], c=X['kmeans'], cmap='rainbow', s=50, alpha=0.8)

# plot X & Y coordinates and color by cluster number
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df_cars, x="hp", y="mpg", color="kmeans", size='mpg', hover_data=['kmeans'])
fig.show()
```

[image]